# godaddy domain linking to aws ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, dns

when i open my website- `www.domainname.com` (example), it is opening but changing to `http://ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/`.

What have I done till now? :

I copied Elastic IP address from AWS EC2 instance and pasted in godaddy's DNS Management in Records containing T`ype A, Name @, Value : My Elastic IP,TTL 1 hour`
[image]

Here is my screenshot:
Could anyone explain why my domain name is changing to aws public dns and how i should overcome it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your website/webserver/app is sending that redirect (using the instance hostname). fix the app, or change instance hostname (in OS)

Comment: This is most likely due to the config of the web server, could you specify which web server you are using (Apache/Nginx/Other) and add their config as well.

Comment: I am trying to upload a wordpress website(static) - installed LAMP web server (followed http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html) and then installed wordpress packages. I religiously followed aws tutorials. I dont know where I am making a mistake!